# Strong name signature not valid for this assembly XAMLMarkupExtensions.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

Strong name signature not valid for this assembly XAMLMarkupExtensions.dll. I tried to publish my project with ClickOnce after publish i have this error. What I do wrong

Comment: Same problem here! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution at the moment is don't use the latest version of XAMLMarkupExtensions.dll from NuGet, but the version 1.5.1. This specific version of this assembly has StrongName=false, so you don't get the error.